# How to get data from database base on calender?

Tags: java, android, calendar, sqliteopenhelper

I created a GridView that showing calendar days for each month

- (7 days* 6 weeks).

Now,I have database table with the above columns:

1. day
2. month
3. year
4. note

e.g:
On my gridView adapter Jan 2015 is:

- grid position 0  is the date 31 of the month before(Dec 2014)
- and to position 41(last day in the calender) is the date 7 of the next month(Feb 2015).

I just want to pull all the data of Jan 2015 base on my calendar it's mean that i need to get all the data between :

- 31/12/2014
- 7/2/2015

any idea what the sql query to getting it?
I spent a lot of time and I could not figure it out :(

Comment: Please Share your Database Structure Along with Code that is creating Issues

Comment: I think your db design is not good, as you should save the dates in a Date column so it would be much easier to fetch later.